# How to show associated options with the "Entity select element" when using Webform + Webform Node

Tags: webforms

I have a webform with an Entity select element. The referenced item is a content type (for example: product). This Product content type has 5 nodes (product 1, product 2 etc.). When viewing the webform it shows a select list with the 5 options (expected).

Now I would like to make use of a node with the webform associated. This content type has the fields Product (entity reference) and webform (to associate the form to the node). When I add 2 products to this node, I would like the webform to only show those 2 products (instead of all) in the Entity select element.

I know there is an option to use a view and tried to use a relationship with contextual filters, but I can't seem to find the right options. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to create this relation. In views I had to add the following settings:

1. Add relation for desired field.
2. Add another relation that is referenced by that content.
3. Add contextual filter NID with a relation to the field selected in step 1.